# Why is percentage in deep linking query changed

Tags: android, deep-linking

I have a deep link set up using the latest navigation component. The link is as follows

`https://example.com/users/{id}?myarg={myarg}`
A sample link is `https://example.com/users/?myarg=DHhshs%sksks%hh&` I noticed that the % character was changed into something else as seen in the diagram below
[image]

What can I do to rectify this?

Answer (score 2):

`%` is a reveserved character in URL query.
It is used for [percent-encoding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding).

If you need to use `%` in the query, you must encode it first to `%25`